# UITabBarController unable to set initial view

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I asked a similar question earlier today but i've run into problems. I'm trying to load the third view the tabbarcontroller when my app is loaded. I have the following in appdelegate, but the first view is still being loaded.

```
appdelegate.m:

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tbc"];

    [tbc setSelectedIndex:2];
    [self.window setRootViewController:tbc];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
```

Appdelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UITabBarController *tbc;

@end
```

I'm sure its something basic I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Some fine points:

1. Did you initialize `self.window`, e.g. something like

   ```
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   ```

   You should set a breakpoint, and make sure that `self.window` is non-nil before you `makeKeyAndVisible`.
2. The way you are declaring `tbc` is as a local variable. If you want to initialize the instance variable you declared as a property, it should be something like this:

   ```
   self.tbc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tbc"];
   ```

Comment: I've tried both those and still no luck. I've set a breakpoint and _window is set to 0x00000001546109c0. I'm still pretty new to Objective-c, is there something basic I may have missed?

Comment: 1. Is tbc non-nil, and a UITabBarController. 2. Do the initialization methods get called on tbc? 3. Do the initialization methods get called on any of tbc's views? 4. What does _window.subviews tell you?